# Is there a clean way to turn an overload set into a visitor suitable for use with std::visit?

Tags: c++, c++17, variant

Suppose I have an overload set, like so:

```
class C
{
  public: 

    static void f(const A &);
    static void f(const B &);
};
```

I'd like to do something like

```
std::variant<A, B> v;

// ...

std::visit(C::f, v);
```

but this doesn't compile.  Is there some way of taking an overload set and regarding it as, or converting it to, a Visitor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, after playing around with this further I've realized that I can do

```
std::visit([](const auto & t) { C::f(t); }, v);
```

so I'll leave this here as a potential solution for anyone else with the same problem.

Comment: You could improve it with perfect forwarding: `[](auto&& arg){ C::f(std::forward<decltype(arg)>(arg));}`. Other than that I believe this is the cleanest solution there is because overload sets simply cannot be passed around.

Comment: @Quimby in general I'd agree that's an improvement, but this particular example set doesn't seem to warrant perfect forwarding, considering each overload only accepts a constant reference.

Comment: @Quimby Could remove the forward and do `decltype(arg)(arg)`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yes, but as soon as an overload uses an rvalue ref, it will fail to compile.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I don't think so? That would not forward it, right? You could do `(decltype(args)&&)(arg)` but that is exactly what `forward` does anyway.

Comment: @Quimby Let's assume it was `T&& arg` instead. `decltype(arg)` would give you `T&&`, not `T`, so `decltype(arg)(arg)` is enough.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I see, you are right, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you already use Boost, [Boost.HOF](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/hof/doc/html/doc/index.html) has a utility to wrap an overload set for you: [`BOOST_HOF_LIFT`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/hof/doc/html/include/boost/hof/lift.html):

```
std::visit(BOOST_HOF_LIFT(C::f), v);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/T4oa5W)

Answer (score 1):

If you can make an instance of class `C`, you could overload the member `operator()` on class `C` to call the appropriate function based on the variant type:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

struct A {};
struct B {};

class C
{
    public:    
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(const T& t) { C::f(t); }

    static void f(const A &) { std::cout << "A\n"; }
    static void f(const B &) { std::cout << "B\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    std::variant<A, B> v_a = A{};
    std::variant<A, B> v_b = B{};
    C c;
    std::visit(c, v_a); // "A"
    std::visit(c, v_b); // "B"
    return 0;
}
```